# Scheduled http DELETE request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, httprequest

I'm using Facebook scores API to store scores from an iPhone game. And to make into a weekly tournament, I would like to reset scores every Monday at the same time. Right now I can reset the scores by doing a manual DELETE request. (Facebook Graph DELETE request /APP_ID/scores with the app token). I'm wondering how I can automate this and avoid doing it by hand every week.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorials on cron](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4275607/tutorials-on-cron)